# Parse.com Framework for Xamarin Unified iOS API

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, parse-platform, xamarin

I just changed my project from the MonoTouch (32 bit) to Xamarin.iOS (64 but) API. I was using [Parse](http://parse.com) before the change just fine, but now I am getting the following error:

> /Users/me/Desktop/app-project/iOS/MTOUCHTASK: Error MT0034: Cannot include both 'monotouch.dll' and 'Xamarin.iOS.dll' in the same Xamarin.iOS project - 'Xamarin.iOS.dll' is referenced explicitly, while 'monotouch.dll' is referenced by 'Parse.iOS, Version=1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. (MT0034) (App.iOS)

Any help resolving this would be great

Answer (score 1):

Are you using http://components.xamarin.com/view/parse? If so, that component has not been upgraded to Unified yet.